# Can you satisfy a generic constraint with an implicit conversion?

Tags: c#, generics, implicit-conversion

Given these types:

```
class A { }
class B
{
    public static implicit operator A(B me)
    {
        return new A();
    }
}

class Test<T> where T : A { }
```

I tried

```
var b = new Test<B>();
```

And expected it to fail, which it did. But the error message is

> The type 'B' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Test'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'B' to 'A'.

<strike>But there *is* an implicit reference conversion from B to A. Is this just a strange message?</strike> There is *not* an implicit reference conversion as Adam Robinson's answer shows. The message is correct.

Note that [MSDN says:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

> where T : (base class name) - The type argument must be or derive from the specified base class.

Which explains why it is not allowed since `B` does not derive from `A`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, what you're trying to do is not possible. An implicit *reference* conversion is not the same thing as an implicit *type* conversion. Your code defines an implicit type conversion, which is where you could do the following:

```
B foo = new B();
A bar = foo;
```

Note, however, that `foo` and `bar` now contain different references. The implicit type conversion creates a *new* instance of `A` that should be (by convention) logically equivalent to `foo`. But the point is that it's a different reference.

A *reference* conversion would be where the reference itself does not change, which means that the type in question must either inherit from (for classes) or implement (for interfaces) the type in question. If I do this:

```
class A { }
class B : A { }
```

Then my code above will now hold the same reference in `foo` and `bar`. This is what is meant by an implicit reference conversion. Conversely, an *explicit* reference conversion would be downcasting, like this:

```
A foo = new B();
B bar = (B)foo;
```

Again, the references are the same, but the cast was explicit.

So, in short, the MSDN documentation is clearer but less precise.

Comment: +1 I didn't understand the difference between a type conversion and a reference conversion.

Comment: I wish that we could have generic constraints to allow us to specify required conversions - that would help when using composition-over-inheritance, though we still need some way to allow implicit conversions to (and from) interfaces with a type-conversion, not a reference-conversion. Oh well.

Answer (score 7):

This is not possible.

An implicit conversion is different than type equivalence.  Just because a type can be converted to another type doesn't mean that it is a specific form of the second type.  As such, it doesn't work for generic constraints.

This makes perfect sense - think of what the compiler would do in the following:

```
class A 
{
    public void Foo();
}
class B
{
    public static implicit operator A(B me)
    {
        return new A();
    }
}
```

Now, say you have:

```
public void Bar<T>(T obj) where T : A
{       
    obj.Foo();
    obj.Foo();
    obj.Foo();
}
```

In order to make this work with conversions (ie: allow calling `Bar(new B())`) - you'd have to construct a NEW object instance inside of that method, as Foo isn't defined on B.  This would be very unexpected, and could lead to some very difficult to discover bugs.  In the above, should the conversion operation happen on every method call?  Should it happen once, and the compiler do some trickery to make it work?  While its possible to imagine ways to handle this, no one way is clear...

Answer (score 1):

Other people have covered it mostly but I thought I'd paste some spec stuff

The full list of what is considered valid is in chapter 6.1.6 of the c# language spec. The key part is the last paragraph that says:

> Reference conversions, implicit or explicit, never change the
>   referential identity of the object being converted. In other words,
>   while a reference conversion may change the type of the reference, it
>   never changes the type or value of the object being referred to.

The full list of conversions is as follows:

> The implicit reference conversions are:
>
> - From any reference-type to object and dynamic.
> - From any class-type S to any class-type T, provided S is derived from T.
> - From any class-type S to any interface-type T, provided S implements T.
> - From any interface-type S to any interface-type T, provided S is derived from T.
> - From an array-type S with an element type SE to an array-type T with an element type TE, provided all of the following are true:
>
>   - S and T differ only in element type. In other words, S and T have the same number of dimensions.
>   - Both SE and TE are reference-types.
>   - An implicit reference conversion exists from SE to TE.
> - From any array-type to System.Array and the interfaces it implements.
> - From a single-dimensional array type S[] to System.Collections.Generic.IList and its base interfaces, provided
>     that there is an implicit identity or reference conversion from S to
>     T.
> - From any delegate-type to System.Delegate and the interfaces it implements.
> - From the null literal to any reference-type.
> - From any reference-type to a reference-type T if it has an implicit identity or reference conversion to a reference-type T0 and
>     T0 has an identity conversion to T.
> - From any reference-type to an interface or delegate type T if it has an implicit identity or reference conversion to an interface or
>     delegate type T0 and T0 is variance-convertible (§13.1.3.2) to T.
> - Implicit conversions involving type parameters that are known to be reference types. See §6.1.10 for more details on implicit
>     conversions involving type parameters.

Answer (score -1):

<s>In your sample code, `B` is not derived from `A`.  Try</s>

```
class B : A
{ 
    public static implicit operator A(B me) 
    { 
        return new A(); 
    } 
}
```

No, it's not a strange message.  An "implicit reference conversion" (Specification section 6.1.6.) is not the same as a "user-defined implicit conversion" (section 6.1.10), which is what you have.

A reference conversion means that you can convert the reference to a given object from one type to another ("reference conversions ... never change the referential identity of the object being converted").

The user-defined implicit conversion can (as your does) return a new, different object.

Comment: Er...that still won't work (the OP is explicitly avoiding inheritance in his sample), and if that code is legal then it should be taken out back and shot.

Comment: @AdamRobinson I hadn't yet posted the edit when you wrote your previous comment.

Comment: @phoog: You should probably post the edit before the comment refering people to it then since I certainly thought the same as Adam.